# ¿Error de instalacion netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, windows, ide

[image: Error para instalacion IDE netbeans]

hola quisiera saber porque aparece este error cuando intento instalar el ide netbeans nose cual es el motivo

creo que la configuracion del path si alguien sabe como configurarlo se lo agradeceria si me ayudara

Comment: ¿Has mirado el log? ¿Aparece ahí información relevante?

Comment: Este error solía pasar con Java9 como unico JDK, pues en sus versiones iniciales netbeans no lo soportaba

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada te recomiendo que te descargues la última versión de Kit de Java para desarrolladores, en seguida configura tu path entrando a

Mi Equipo o Este Equipo -> Clic derecho y seleccionar propiedades -> `Configuración Avanzada del Sistema`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después se abre la siguiente ventana y dar clic en el cuadro negro llamado `Variables de Entorno`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de esto añadir a las `Variables del Sistema` la siguiente ruta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y listo, con eso ya tienes configurado tu `Path`